# Is there any way to use Cesiumjs to import 3D Models using the British National Grid (OSGB36)?

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, openlayers, cesium

I am trying to import a 3D model (.gltf) into Cesium which is in OSGB36 projection, however I know that [Cesiumjs](https://cesiumjs.org/) doesn't [support](https://twitter.com/kalifa17/status/718065010061258752) British projection natively.

I've tried changing the origin of the map and reporject the lat and lon based on the x,y,z coordinates cesium's api gives you using entity.position.getValue().

```
var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    // Lon, Lat, Height, Elipsode
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-10.6658787,50.6943631),
    model : {
        uri : '../../static/structures/models/duck/duck.gltf'
    }
});
```

I am looking for which would be the best and quickest way to include this 3d Models, because also would like to use OL3-Cesium to integrate Cesiumjs and Openlayers 3 which only support  EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857 projections and not British.